# Data frame columns contains many newline (\n) and its value respectively .How to separate it as new columns and values too

Tags: pandas, dataframe, newline, python-camelot

While reading the PDF table using camelot  some columns are concatenated and their values too like below

```
Date      | Facture-ref\nfactureid|     Description\items|  Payé\nEscompte  |DÃ©boursÃ©\nPaiement\net
--------------------------------------------------------------------
12/12/2019| 45333\n34343          |     7899\nscrewio    |  89\n0.00        |3443.12\n231232.00\n456
12/12/2019| 453343\n3434          |     7845\nscrewio    |  78\n0.00        |34.12\n232.00\455
```

**my output should be like below**

```
Date        |facture |      Facture |      factureid | Description| items  |   Payé |  Escompte|  DÃ©boursÃ© |   Paiement |    net
-----------------------------------------------------
 12/12/2017 |  45333 |       34343  |     #al: 7899  |    screwio |    89  |   0.00 |   3443.12|   231232.00 |   456|
 12/12/2017 | 453343 |         3434 |    #rfp: 7845  |    screwio |    78  |   0.00 |    34.12 |     232.00  |   455  |
```

I want columns and values to be separated based on newline.

you experiment create using the below df

data = [['12/12/2019', '45333\n34343','7899\nscrewio','89\n0.00','3443.12\n231232.00\n456'],
['12/12/2019', '232\n3434','7845\nnuts','78\n0.00','34.12\n232.00\455']
]

df33 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Date', 'Facture-ref\nfactureid','Description\nitems','Payé\nEscompte','DÃ©boursÃ©\nPaiement\nnet'])

Comment: What parameters are you giving while reading the pdf. I don't use camelot. However, documentation shows that you need to use `camelot.read_pdf('12s0324.pdf', flavor='stream', strip_text=' .\n')` something like this to strip `\n`   https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there's a more elegant way of doing this, but this should work.

edit: with and without dropped. Feel free to post a sample dataset if I'm misunderstanding you.
sample data:

```
>>> data = {'col_1':['a']*5,
    'col_2\ncol_3':['b\nc']*5,
    'col_4':['d']*5}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>> df
  col_1 col_2\ncol_3 col_4
0     a         b\nc     d
1     a         b\nc     d
2     a         b\nc     d
3     a         b\nc     d
4     a         b\nc     d
```

with drop:

```
>>> for col in [i for i in df.columns if '\n' in i]:
    df[col.split('\n')]=df[col].str.split('\n',expand=True)
    df.drop(columns=col,inplace=True)
>>> df
  col_1 col_4 col_2 col_3
0     a     d     b     c
1     a     d     b     c
2     a     d     b     c
3     a     d     b     c
4     a     d     b     c
```

without drop:

```
>>> for col in [i for i in df.columns if '\n' in i]:
    df[col.split('\n')]=df[col].str.split('\n',expand=True)
>>> df
  col_1 col_2\ncol_3 col_4 col_2 col_3
0     a         b\nc     d     b     c
1     a         b\nc     d     b     c
2     a         b\nc     d     b     c
3     a         b\nc     d     b     c
4     a         b\nc     d     b     c
```

Comment: Always try to fix the problem at source instead of doing it afterwards. This may solve the problem

Comment: hi , i used this code but it deletes the col itself ..

Comment: @KesavaMurthi the code creates two new columns from the original split column, so without the drop you'd have the original + the 2 products of the split. If you want to keep the original column, just remove the 'df.drop' line. Check the edited answer.